# Can we rename a database in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I just started with neo4j and I could not find a way to rename a database in neo4j.

Is it possible and how to do so?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (in neo4j 4.1.1) [no support for renaming a database](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/manage-databases/configuration/).

You may want to open a [feature request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature&template=feature_request.md&title=) for that capability.